# Javascript: how to print return value of function?

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I'm beginner to Javascript and reading Closures and Variables part of book "JS for web developers". It gives two examples:

```
function Func1() {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function() {
           console.log('i:'+i);
           return i; 
        };
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(Func1());

function Func2() {
    var result = new Array();

    for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function(num) {
            return function() {
                console.log('num:'+num);
                return num;
            };
        }(i);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(Func2());
```

In the book's description, it said in func1, every function could return 10, while in func2, each function would return different number. But when I run the code, it actually returns:

```
[ [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function],
  [Function] ]
```

for both functions.

So how to print out actual values for each function? And why "console.log('i:'+i);" is not printed in first function?

Comment: To print the return value of a function, you have to call it first. E.g. `var arr = Func1(); arr[3]();`

Comment: @L.L you need to wrap the function so it will invoke. Currently you are assigning a function to the variable. You want to invoke the function and return the result into the variable. Check my example below.

Comment: `var fncs = Func1(); console.log(fncs[0]()); console.log(fncs[1]())`

Answer (score 3):

Try this wrap your result[i] data into a invoked function to get the data you need...

check this:

```
function Func1() {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = (function() {
           console.log('i:'+i);
           return i; 
        })();
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(Func1());
```

Comment: Now I can  get value of the function. But now func1 and func2 get the same result? [0,...,9]. Do you know why?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: In the book's description, the first function should return 10 for each function. The second function should return 0-9 for each function. But now both functions return [0,...,9].

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a function in your for loop, instead you should just return the value inside of your closure.

```
function Func2() {
    var result = new Array();

    for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function(num) {
            console.log('num:'+num);
            return num;
        }(i);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(Func2());
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the current output of the execution of the function, an `Array` of functions, you can iterate the result of `FuncN` then execute the function at each element of the array

```
for (let n = 0, f = Func1(); n < f.length; n++) {
  console.log(f[n]())
}
```

Comment: console.log(f[n])? Otherwise, it prompts f is not function.

Comment: @L.L No. Did not re-write the code at the question. The code at the answer executes each function in the array and prints the result to `console`

Comment: Thanks, through this way, I could get all 10 for each function in func1.

Answer (score 1):

Try them like this:

```
function Func1() {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function() {
           console.log('i:'+i);
           return i; 
        }();
    }
return result;

}

console.log(Func1());

function Func2() {
    var result = new Array();

    for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function(num) {
            return function() {
                console.log('num:'+num);
                return num;
            }();
        }(i);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(Func2());
```

the problem is due the fact that you have set the function as it's return value rather than calling it and then returning.

Comment: Now I can get value of the function. Both functions return [0,...,9]. But in the book's description, the first function should return 10 for each function. The second function should return 0-9 for each function. Do you know why?